# Ajax username and date Instagram API

Tags: ajax, api, date, instagram

Currently, I'm trying to create a page using instagram's api, showing recent pictures with a specific tag, as well as the user who posted it and the date posted.  I'm also trying to have the infinite loading functionality, with ajax loading in more instagram posts as the page reaches the bottom.

Heres a link to the live site http://www.laithazzam.com/work/nukes/indexnew.php

Clicking the red yes will skip the video, and go straight to the instagram feed.

I'm currently using Christian Metz's solution found here, https://gist.github.com/cosenary/2961185

I am also having an issue with posting the date, in the first initial load, as well in the ajax loads. I was previously able to use this following code, before trying to implement Christian's php/ajax solution.

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(data.data[i].created_time) * 1000);
<p class='date'>"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate()+"/"+date.getFullYear()+"</p>
```

I guess what I don't understand, is how the ajax loading function, is actually functioning. How would I also pull the name, and date through the ajax loading success function as well?

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'ajax.php',
      data: {
        tag: tag,
        max_id: maxid
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        // Output data
        $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
        $("#instafeed").append('<img src="' + src + '">');
        });

        // Store new maxid
        $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` parameter of the `success` handler function is populated from whatever JSON ajax.php returns and the structure will match accordingly. It looks like the images attribute of that object only has an array of URLs for the images and no other data.

You'll need to [update this section of the PHP script](https://gist.github.com/cosenary/2961185#file-ajax-php-L36) to return more than just the array of URLs for the images and also include the additional data retrieved from the Instagram API.

Try updating the last part to this:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id,
    'images'  => $media->data
));
```

Then you'll have full access to all the media data, not just the URL.

Comment: Oh, right on, thanks that makes sense.

What is still a little fuzzy, is what is making jquery output that array of information, the src of the image?

the <img src="' + src + '"> part, I don't exactly understand how that relates to the instagram api, and what would pull just the username instead?

Comment: The `$.each()` method is looping over the images array which contains strings of URLs for the image source and calling the function for each of them. Each time the function is called the `i` is set to the position in the array and the `src` is a variable set to the value for the current iteration. If you change your server to return the full media object, you'd need to do something like `$.each(data.images, function(i, image) { ... });` inside that block you can do `image.user.name` or whatever the JSON attribute names are to get the data you need.

Comment: okay cool, and changing my server to return that full media object, would that be using the change you've previously pointed out, the $media->data, or does it involve these lines instead?

$images = array();
      foreach ($media->data as $data) {
        $images[] = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;
      }

Comment: you can ignore the lines that populate $images since you're using the superset of that data